# Fatal error: Call to a member function insert_id() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\county\application\core\MY_Model.php on line 50

Tags: codeigniter

i have that type of error at line 50 where i have the below line of code

```
        $id->$this->db->insert_id();
        help please ,the screenshot the my_model
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of Model

```
class Model_name extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

> Where `Model_name` is the name of your class. Class names must have the **first letter capitalized with the rest of the name lowercase**. Make sure your class extends the base Model class.

and Calling function will be

```
function insert_id()
{
    //your code
    $id->$this->db->insert_id();
}
```

To Call Model Function in controller

```
$result = $this->Model_name->insert_id()//can pass data to the function as well,(Ex: insert_id($id))
```

[Codeigniter Model Naming](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html)

Answer (score 0):

i think your code is wrong

```
function insert_id()
{
    //your code
    $id->$this->db->insert_id();
}
```

should be

```
function insert_id()
{
    //your code
    $id = $this->db->insert_id();
    return $id;
}
```